# React bootstrap opening all collapse

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I got this example from [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/utilities/transitions/#collapse) and updated to add another new button with collapse component.

```
function Example() {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

return (
<>
  <Button
    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
    aria-expanded={open}
  >
    click
  </Button>
  <Collapse in={open}>
    <div id="example-collapse-text">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
      terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
      labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
  </Collapse>
  <Button
    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
    aria-expanded={open}
  >
    click
  </Button>
   <Collapse in={open}>
    <div id="example-collapse-text">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
      terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
      labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
  </Collapse>
</>
);}
```

I want to know how can I open only a selected collapse. As of now when I click on any of those buttons it opens all.

I don't want to maintain separate state for each collapse, as in my case, I will have this value dynamically provided by the API so having 10 of these collapse instances means maintaining 10 states. Is there any better solution to address this?

Comment: Make a reusable component that manages its own open state, has its own button and `Collapse` etc. Then render as many of them as you need and they will only open one at a time.

Comment: is there a way to do this without creating an extra component? Can you point me to any code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to accomplish this without creating a new component.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        shown : {}
    };
}

toggle(index) {
    this.setState({
        shown: {
            ...this.state.shown,
            [index]: !this.state.shown[index]
        }
    });
}
```

And then use this as:

```
<Container id={index} key={index}>
...
...
   <Row>
       <Col onClick={() => this.toggle(index)}>Click</Col>
   </Row>
...
</Container>
```

And the toggle:

```
<Collapse in={this.state.shown[index]}>
...
    <Row>
        ...
    </Row>
...
</Collapse>
```